# bushy, left-deep and right-deep in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I searched for the terms bushy, left-deep and right-deep after I saw them in the context of query plans in SQL.
I have found some entries but still don't understand the differences between those. May you explain me what it's about?

Edit:
I'm self-studying SQL and want to improve in this topic. I'm working with Sybase and started now to use Joins. I saw a description of these terms on this page http://dbakevlar.com/2014/05/right-deep-left-deep-and-bushy-joins-in-sql/ but the symbols and vocabulary is above my level at the moment. It's not about a special query, I just want to have a rough understanding to know how to differentiate those terms.

Comment: Please provide some context for your question.  What are the references?  What database?  Do you have a particular query in mind?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/08/10/hash-join/

Comment: So, from that one post, did you follow the link in the "further reading" section that purported to be "SQL 101" for the topic?

Comment: I will read myself through  
blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/08/10/hash-join  and the "SQL 101" link. Obviously, I need to understand Hash Joins better. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If youre using Sybase then looking at more Sybase related joins and plan optimization would probably be a better idea. Lots of the plan optimization steps on that page won't work for Sybase.